# Couldn't copy paste text from local computer(win 11) to AVD through Remote Desktop App

Tags: remote-desktop, group-policy, copy-paste, clipboard

I couldn't copy paste text from local computer(windows 11) to AVD (Azure virtual Desktop) through Remote Desktop App. Copy paste works in both AVD & local computer, if i use RD web client.

All settings seem fine. Is it a clipboard issue or GPO or what?
Is the issue with RD app or with laptop?

Comment: What are you remote desktoping onto?

Comment: Connecting to AVD using the RD App
(But copy paste works in both AVD & local computer, if i use RD webclient)

Comment: I assume you have enabled Clipboard sharing in the Windows Remote Desktop Connection "Local Resources" tab before connecting?

Comment: Please don't answer in comments. If you have new info to add, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1772400/edit) the question instead so relevant info is readily available.

Comment: No.. I found clipboard option is in gradeout state in RDC.
But how does it affect cause i don't use RDConnection?
See, I open Remote Desktop APP >Click on AVD.
I'm sorry, i'm quite unaware of this.
I can copy paste in respective sessions but not between my comp and AVD